# I can't figure how to prove this coordinate algebraic geometry proof.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-without-words

> 1. Consider the points $A$ and $C$ are on $y=x^p$. We are told that point $A$ has coordinates $( a, b )$, where $0<a<1$ and point $C$ has coordinates $( c, d )$, where
>      $1<c$.  
>     Give a convincing argument that
>      $b+d$ must be greater than $1$.
> 2. Two points on the graph of $y=kx^p$ are labeled $A$ and $C$.  Point $A$ has coordinates $(a,b)$, where $0<a<1$ and point $C$ has coordinates $(c,d)$, where
>      $1<c$. 
>    If we are told that that the product
>      $k\cdot p$ is negative, what can be concluded about the points $A$ and $C$? 
>      Defend your answer.

I can't figure it out. Can someone help. I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  For 1, consider what happens depending on the sign of $p$.  If I tell you $p \lt 0$, what can you conclude?

For 2, what can you say about the sign of $\frac {dy}{dx}?$  Does that let you say something interesting about $b,d?$

Comment: If p<0, and 0<a<1, then a^p=1/a^−p=(1/a)^−p, where 1/a>1 and −p>0 is what I got. Also, what does dy/dx mean.

Comment: Did you get 1?  $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is the slope of the curve.  You will see that in calculus-I thought you might have studied that.  The point is that $y$ is decreasing, so $a \lt b \implies c \gt d$.  Can you prove that?